# On click accordion twice arrow position doesn't change

Tags: jquery, css

I have accordion for that I used "up" and "down" arrow's, it works fine but, when I click again on panel-title arrow doesn't change.

**Explain :**

In this example I used "A" and "B" instead of "up" and "down" arrow,
When page load all panel-title shows "A",
Once clicked on panel-title "A" change to "B" but again clicked on "B" it doesn't change to "A".

```
$('#leftMenu .panel-title a').click(function(){
  $('#leftMenu .panel-title a').parent('.panel-title').removeClass('accordion-opened'); 
  $(this).parent('.panel-title').addClass('accordion-opened');
});
```

**[JSFiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/alpeshlahad/mLyLj622/2/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution would work. [**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/mLyLj622/7/).

Modify your JS to skip the current/clicked one.

```
$('#leftMenu .panel-title a').click(function() {
  $('#leftMenu .panel-title').not($(this).parent('.panel-title')).removeClass('accordion-opened');
  $(this).parent('.panel-title').toggleClass('accordion-opened');
});
```

**Note:**

Solution by **Aneesh Sivaraman** is failing. To check:

1. Click the second accordion(`Program Description`) once.
2. Now click the first accordion(`Issue Type`) - It still shows **`A`**

Comment: When I click rapidly two times on the up/down button it gets toggled incorrectly. How to eliminate that?

Answer (score 2):

Please check this [`updated fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/mLyLj622/9/)

No need to add 'accordion-opened' class when we click second time.

Comment: i have added a boolean variable for that. Please check the answer fiddle.

Comment: @Appy : Solution by **Aneesh Sivaraman** is failing. **To check :** Click the second accordion(`Program Description`) once.
Now click the first accordion(`Issue Type`) - It still shows **`A`**

Answer (score 2):

You can add class by your own and then add and remove `accordion-opened` class according to that

```js
$('#leftMenu .panel-title a').click(function() {
  $('#leftMenu .panel-title a').parent('.panel-title').removeClass('accordion-opened');
  if ($(this).hasClass('opened')) {
    $(this).removeClass('opened');
    $(this).parent('.panel-title').removeClass('accordion-opened');
  } else {
    $(this).addClass('opened');
    $(this).parent('.panel-title').addClass('accordion-opened');
  }
});
```

```css
#leftMenu .accordion-toggle:after {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  content: "A";
  float: right;
}
#leftMenu .accordion-opened .accordion-toggle:after {
  content: "B";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="leftMenu" class="panel-group">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#leftMenu" href="#tab-1">Issue Type</a>
       </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="tab-1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <h1>Issue Type</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title"> 
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#leftMenu"  href="#tab-2">Program Description</a>
       </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="tab-2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <h1>Program Description</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--/#leftMenu-->
```

Comment: This is failing for the very first time!!

Comment: Still some issue! Please try multiple combinations.